# C++ Visual studio 2012 error C3861: '_T': identifier not found?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, unicode, macros, mfc

I have installed visual studio 2012 on 64 bit windows 7, and trying to build MFC Project, but on first debug always appear error:

```
Error   1   error C3861: '_T': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlexcept.h   66
Error   3   error C3861: '_T': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h   556
Error   4   error C3861: '_T': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h   589
...
```

**Where those _T macro have to be define? Why those problem appear?**

Comment: You simply have to #include <tchar.h>

Comment: where do you mean to put  #include <tchar.h> if error appear in header files ...?

Comment: include it in your header file.

Comment: unfortunately nothing happens

Answer (score 3):

`#include <tchar.h>`  should work. If it is not.. Then try to do this ;

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#define _T(x)      L ## x
#else /* _UNICODE */
#define _T(x)      x
#endif /* _UNICODE */
```

Comment: i give you up vote for effort but none of those work in my exact example

Comment: Can you share part of your code where you got this error message. If you give more information then we may understand why you get error.

Comment: Well all other errors are same as posted, the problem appear in default c++ headers (which is processed before any compilation is start) so i'm searching for solution on visual studio layer, should i install it again to repair headers of just insert in one header those your code ...

Comment: no just basic mfc application with header files, i found out that problem appear somewhere in visual studio ...